# Trying to convert the value of a textbox to an int C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, string, timer, int

I am currently trying to use the value of a textbox as the value of an integer in a Timer so its like this

User inputs a value 
my application reads it and uses the input as a value of interval in a timer
 but its giving me this error, whats going on?
[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uow8s.png)

Comment: Have you had a look what `TextBox.Text`actually returns? It´s obviously not an integer, it´s a string, isn´t it? So you should convert the string to an int, google this and you´re done.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Convert into Integer from string.Then you can use it.
exp:

```
 int timeInterval = Convert.ToInt32(txtTime.Text);
```

Use can use the Variable value(timeInterval).

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep()` takes an integer value, but you are passing the string value into the function. Any value taken from the user input like as `Textbox.Text` is treated as `string` and you need to convert that to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert your String to Int like so:

```
int timeInterval = Int32.Parse(txtTime.Text);
```